the infinite category constructed from a model category has all limits and colimits
I am reading a survey on derived algebraic geometry. On the page 28, I read such a paragraph:
Let $C$ be a model category, and $I$ be a small category, let $C^{I}$ be the model category of diagrams in the shape of $I$. It is shown that there exists a natural equivalence of infinite categories:
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ $ L(C^{I})\cong Fun^{\infty}(I,L(C))$
Here $L(-)$ corresponds to the infinite category constructed from the model category $-$.
Then the survey says that 'thus $L(C)$ always has (co)limits and can be computed using the well-known homotopy (co)limits of homotopical algebras'. Can any one shows me how to understand the equivalence above and deduce the conclusions from this equivalence?
Remark: the left hand side of the equivalence is the infinite categorification of the diagram category and the right hand side is the infinite category of infinite functors between infinite categories, which is quite difficult to describe in the context of this survey (see page 27 of this survey for this construction).

The main idea in slogan form is the following: Model categories have homotopy (co-)limits and so the $\infty$-category associated to a model category will obtain these (co-)limits and they can be computed in the model category. This is one way to make precise that $\infty$-categorical (co-)limits are what's classically seen as homotopy (co-)limits.
In the particular setting of your referenced survey the idea is roughly the following: First, let's ignore fibrancy/cofibrancy problems and assume that everything is as nice as possible, as $L$ inverts weak equivalences and thus (co-)fibrant replacements. A ($\infty$-categorical) colimit of $L(C)$ is by definition the same thing as a ($\infty$-categorical) left adjoint of the ($\infty$-categorical) diagonal functor $L(C) \to \operatorname{Fun}^{\infty}(I, L(C))$. On the other hand,
$$ L(C) \to \operatorname{Fun}^{\infty}(I, L(C)) \simeq L(C^I), $$
but now we can use that $C \to C^I$ has a Quillen left adjoint since homotopy colimits in $C$ exist. This Quillen left adjoint is transferred to an $(\infty$-categorical) left adjoint.
The limit case works the same way through considering the right adjoint of the diagonal functor.
